# PHP e Highcharts, duvida listar series

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

Fiz uma consulta com o php e estou iterando com meu array usando Foreach para setar no `Highcharts` os valores da seguinte forma:

```
series: [<?php  $i =0;
            foreach($result as $rs) { ?>{
                name: '<?php echo $rs['ConteudoNome'];?>',
                data: [ <?php echo $rs['TreinoTempo']; ?>]

            },<?php } ?>
```

E o resultado fica assim:

```
series: [{
                name: 'Corrida',
                data: [ 60]

            },{
                name: 'Ataque',
                data: [ 51]

            },{
                name: 'Corrida',
                data: [ 50]

            },
            ]
```

Preciso que o resultado seja algo como "Corrida" [60,50]
ou seja, quando o `ConteudoNome` for igual, ele apenas acrescente o valor e não crie outra serie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deduzindo que seu array esteja assim:`[{name:'Corrida', dados:"50"},{name:'Corrida', dados:"60"},{name:'Ataque',dados:"51"}]`
o ideia seria colocar ele no formato:

```
[{name:'Corrida', dados: [50,60]},
{name:'Ataque', dados: [51]}]
```

Assim basta apenas inserir o array nas `series`. Fiz um código que remove os duplicados e coloca no formato correto.

Veja funcionado.

```js
  var array1 = [
        { name: 'Corrida', dado: 50 },
        { name: 'Corrida', dado: 60 },
        { name: 'Ataque', dado: 51 }
            ];
            var result = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                var item = new Object();
                item.name = array1[i].name;
                item.data = new Array();
                item.data.push(parseInt(array1[i].dado));

                for (var j = i + 1; j < array1.length; j++) {
                    if (array1[i].name === array1[j].name) {
                        item.data.push(parseInt(array1[j].dado));
                        array1.splice(j, 1);
                    }
                }
                result.push(item);
            }


            $('#container').highcharts({
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: result
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Segui seu conselho, porem quando eu vou passar meu array já no formato JSON para o JS, não da certo. Dei um alert e ele fica Object object; Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @LuanGabriel da um console.log(seuarray) e veja como está seu array usando f12->console.

Comment: Ae, no console.log o array apareceu ok, porem ele não tá montando no grafico.

Comment: @LuanGabriel fez a importação do highchats.js e do Jquery.js? Repare que o Jquery vem antes.

Comment: Fiz sim, eu acho que o problema está no "series: result".  Eu ja tentei sem sucesso fazer isso há alguns dias atrás de jogar um array em JSON direto no series

Comment: Não acho que seja isso, pois o código acima está a funcionar. Clique em `Executar trecho de código` e verá. Acho que você está esquecendo algum detalhe na adaptação desse código para o seu.

Comment: Entra no chat pra gente descutir sobre. continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32104/discussion-between-marconi-and-luan-gabriel).